# Get User ID Changed in Joomla Site

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I Installed two Components in my Joomla website. After Login my site. I print User Id, that id is 22. and goto one component page(Site Part) I print User Id, that id is 3 (super User). Why User Id is Changing. what is my Mistake?

Answer (score 1):

May be in that component they load super user , eg., in email template they have to send email to admin and super user.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);
```

using this we can change user object by passing user id